# Samba not showing symbolic links

Tags: permissions, samba

I am trying to use symbolic links with samba to link to a file outside the samba share directory. I've search around and have updated the config file with all the suggestions, but still no luck.

This is my smb.conf file:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes

allow insecure wide links = yes
unix extensions = no

[Private]
path = /media/hdd1/samba/private/
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
writable = yes
valid users = @samba
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
```

When I try testparm I get the following output

```
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    allow insecure wide links = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    unix extensions = No
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    unix password sync = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[Private]
    comment = House private samba share
    path = /media/hdd1/samba/private/
    wide links = Yes
    read only = No
    valid users = @samba
```

The follow symlinks is inclided in the config file, but not on the testparm output which I think is a bit odd.

The stripped down simple file structure is:

```
/media
|- hdd1
   |- datafolder
   |  |-- file1
   |
   |- samba
      |-- private
          |-- Symbolic link to file1
```

Permissions are:

```
file1  root  plugdev
link   samba sambashare
```